# Why is the entry not being added?

Tags: django

i am trying to add entries without using forms.py. But when saving, it redirects me to a non-existent page and does not save the product. Maybe a simple question but it puzzled me

`views`

```
def create(request):
    if (request.method == 'POST'):
        obj, created = Posts.objects.get_or_create(title=request.POST.get("title"))
        obj.text=request.POST.get("text")

        obj.save()
        
    return render(request, 'create.html ')
```

`html`

```
  <form action="save" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="text" placeholder="Название" name="title"><br>
        <textarea placeholder="Текст статьи" rows="8" cols="80" name="text"></textarea><br>
        <input type="date" name="date"><br>
        <button type="submit">Добавить статью</button>
      </form>
```

`models`

```
class Posts(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField('Название', max_length=100, blank=True)
    anons = models.CharField('Анонс', max_length=250, blank=True)
    text = models.TextField('Текст статьи', blank=True)
    date = models.DateField('Дата публикации', blank=True)
```

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ovlT.png)

Comment: Remove white space `'create.html '`. If it doesn't help, share full traceback error.

Comment: @NKSM i UPD question with error But it just 404, i dont know why it redirect me to /save page

Comment: Where did you define the URL "`save`", or the `urlpattern` for `create`…?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though, you haven't shared the app's url file. Let guess you have  written it like that in the **urls.py**

```py
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views 
app_name = "your_app_name"

urlpatterns = [
   path('',views.create, name="your_view_name"),

]
```

Then, you when you want to execute the view function. You have to mention it inside the
starting form tag in action. **in template:**

```
<form action="{% url "your_app_name:your_view_name" %}" method="post" >
        {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="text" placeholder="Название" name="title"><br>
    <textarea placeholder="Текст статьи" rows="8" cols="80" name="text"></textarea><br>
    <input type="date" name="date"><br>
    <button type="submit"> Добавить статью</button>
</form>
```